# Is the use of "inside" correct in the sentence below?

Tags: word-choice

They started to open fire into the house they obviously couldn’t see **inside**.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't start to open fire. You either open fire or start firing. Re the other, conciseness is always good. E.g., They started firing blindly into the house.

Comment: Hi, welcome, please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

In brief, it is grammatically correct but aesthetically speaking - ugly and obtuse.

There's not much else to say.

What made you think that there was something wrong with it?

Comment: It didn't sound right to me either. Can you propose an alternative plz?